# SQL Count() need 0 as well

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, conditional-aggregation

I just have one table and i want to count every entry for label where start is 0

right now i try it like this:

`SELECT label, COUNT(start) AS Anzahl, user_id FROM datensammlung Where (start='1') AND (user_id='1') GROUP BY label;`

But the return is only:

| Label | Anzahl | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_Eating spoon | 20 | 1 |
| 1_Nose Blowing | 20 | 1 |

But i would like to have it like that:

| Label | Anzahl | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_Eating spoon | 20 | 1 |
| 1_Nose Blowing | 20 | 1 |
| 1_phone | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Sum/group by like this won't give you your desired result.  You have to build a list of labels and left join to that.

Comment: Okay how would that look like ? I am relatively new to SQL and never used a Join on the same table. Thanks for the information

Comment: You will need the list of all available labels. See https://learnsql.com/blog/zero-as-result-of-count-in-sql/

Comment: Do you have another table that has all the possible labels? If not, where should `1_phone` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all `label`s are available in the table, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT label, 
       SUM(user_id = '1' AND start = '1') AS Anzahl 
FROM datensammlung 
GROUP BY label;
```